# Is it safe to install packages with multiple instances of emerge running at the same time?

Tags: system-installation, gentoo, emerge, portage

I'm currently installing Gentoo by following the Handbook. I ran `emerge -uDN @world` after changing USE flags and it's taking hours, but I would like to continue with [the next step](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Kernel). Is it fine to `emerge` the kernel and other packages I'll need in a separate tty without waiting for it to finish?

Pacman prevents you from running multiple instances by checking for `pacman.lock`, but emerge doesn't seem to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No and yes, `emerge` like `pacman` discourages multiple instances.  A lock is created during the dependency checking phase(the dependency graph is  then put in RAM)  and the install phase, but not during the compile phase, as @Eduardo noted, this allows multiple runs of `emerge`(and single writes to the `vdb`, but the same package can be compiled twice, which some consider counter productive. Most users choose to use the option `--keep-going` should breakage occur.

In  order to speed up your `emerge --newuse --update` consider using the `--jobs` option.  See [Parallel Builds With Gentoo's Emerge](https://www.preney.ca/paul/archives/341), and have a look at `man emerge`

Answer (score 3):

From the question [Can multiple emerge commands be run at the same time?](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8611020.html) in the Gentoo forum.

> Yes, I have run emerge in different VT's simultaneously. Caution: If the emerge's want to install the same thing or the same dependencies, each will calculate what needs to be done only once depending on the predicate of your command.
> Example if you are building @world in one VT then start @system in the other, you may well be emerging the same rging twice, say if calculate gcc needs updating in the first and the second, both will emerge gcc independently. Portage only checks once for each invocation.

The main problem is that even if everything works, you might be wasting resources by rebuilding the same thing multiple times, slowing everything else down.